# Getting warning when generating sprites with compass / sass

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I have an issue with compass Im not able to find out.

Every time I compile, when compass find a intruction like:

```
@import "base-icons/*.png";
```

Compass throw:

```
WARNING: Compass::SpriteImporter should define the #public_url method.
```

Actually, it compiles and everything is working fine.

Unfortunately, I cannot find information about this issue, and I hate to see warnings on my console.

Anyone know what could be happening ? How can I get rid of this ? Or which are the consequences of this message, what does it mean ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is reflected here:

https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/1108

And solved on the release tagged as: "import-once-1.0.4"